# Counterparty risk tutorials

Tags: credit-risk

I want to learn about the latest methods used to measure credit risk, which I believe is same as counterparty risk. Can you please direct me some links for this. I have come across a few of them but each of them seems to be talking a different way to measure counterparty risk. eg basel-3 .

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a tutorial on the Internet but I have a book on the topic that I think you could be interested in:

[Counterparty Credit Risk and Credit Value Adjustment: A Continuing Challenge for Global Financial Markets](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1118316673)

The book is a non-mathematical introduction to counter-party credit risk. It introduces concepts such as wrong-way risk, netting, potential-future exposure etc. Please give a try.

Answer (score 0):

[Good lecture on credit risk here.](http://www.maths.univ-evry.fr/pages_perso/jeanblanc/doctorat.html)

For more recent and advanced tools  you should read books and articles from: Brigo, Rebonato, Pykhtin.

Comment: Your link is dead, and I'm not sure you had the right to share this anyway. However, you can include links to the books and articles you mention.

Comment: All of the member homepages of mathematics department at that university are currently broken - I think the link will be fixed at some point.